# Cannot reference an xml-drawable from a style

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'm trying to specify a reference/resource-id to a drawable from a custom style.

If the drawable is an image file (ie, .png), everything is ok, however if the drawable is a xml layout file (ie, a selector), then I get the compile-time error:

> No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'net.monocross.app:button_drawable_id' with value
>   '@layout/XmlSelector') ..\Resources\values\styles.xml

I'm trying to determine if this is an Android rule, or maybe a Monodroid issue, and if there are other means to this end ?

Thanks.

**styles.xml**

```
<style name ="DropdownButtonA">
  <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/button_width</item>
  <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/button_height</item>
  <item name="net.monocross.app:button_label_text">hi</item>
  <item name="net.monocross.app:button_label_color">#99ABCDEF</item>

  <!-- OK --> 
  <item name="net.monocross.app:button_drawable_id">@drawable/PngImage</item>

  <!-- ERROR -->
  <item name="net.monocross.app:button_drawable_id">@drawable/XmlSelector</item>

</style>
```

**attrs.xml**

```
<declare-styleable name="DropdownButton">
  <attr name="button_label_text" format="string"></attr>
  <attr name="button_label_color" format="color"></attr>  
  <attr name="button_drawable_id" format="reference"></attr>
</declare-styleable>
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to rename the xml-drawable file

> XmlSelector.axml -> xml_selector.xml

If that doesn't work for you, just try keeping the .axml extension.